# Decode JSON when JSON is stored as a variable in R Dataframe

Tags: r, json

I am wondering how to "decode" JSON when JSON code is stored as a character variable in a R data frame column. Neither jsonlite nor JSONIO helped me up to this point. The data looks as followed:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(3,4)
c <- c("{\"openingTimes\":[{\"applicable_days\":64,\"periods\":[{\"startp\":\"07:30\",\"endp\":\"21:00\"}]}]}", "{}")
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `fromJSON` is vectorized.

```
library(jsonlite)
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(3,4)
c <- c("{\"openingTimes\":[{\"applicable_days\":64,\"periods\":[{\"startp\":\"07:30\",\"endp\":\"21:00\"}]}]}", "{}")
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c))
> sapply(data$c, fromJSON)
$`{"openingTimes":[{"applicable_days":64,"periods":[{"startp":"07:30","endp":"21:00"}]}]}`
$`{"openingTimes":[{"applicable_days":64,"periods":[{"startp":"07:30","endp":"21:00"}]}]}`$openingTimes
  applicable_days      periods
1              64 07:30, 21:00


$`{}`
named list()
```